# Frame Query for Nested class parameter to consume WCF Service from SSRS

Tags: wcf, reporting-services

Trying to consume the WCF Service in SSRS. Not able to frame the query since the method parameter is a nested class. Below embedded the WCFService definition and the QUERY in SS.

WCF Definition:

```cs
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        int GetDataUsingDataContract1(CompositeType1 composite, int val);
        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType1
    {

        CompositeType _compositeType;
        int _intValue = 1;

        [DataMember]
        public CompositeType compositeType
        {
            get { return _compositeType; }
            set { _compositeType = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int intValue
        {
            get { return _intValue; }
            set { _intValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Query in SSRS for consuming the WCF Service

```xml
<Query>
    <Method  Name="GetDataUsingDataContract1" Namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name ="composite" Type="XML" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1">
                <Parameter Name ="compositeType" Type="XML" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1">
                    <DefaultValue>
                        <BoolValue>1</BoolValue>
                        <StringValue> Testing</StringValue>
                    </DefaultValue>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter Name="val"><DefaultValue>10</DefaultValue></Parameter>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter Name="intval"><DefaultValue>10</DefaultValue></Parameter>
        </Parameters>
    </Method>
    <SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract</SoapAction>
</Query>
```

But the above query is not working.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is a problem with the xml structure you query, and the WCF service cannot receive this message. According to the interface you provide, the message received by the WCF service should look like the following:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract1</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetDataUsingDataContract1 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <composite xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApp136" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:compositeType i:nil="true" />
        <a:intValue>0</a:intValue>
      </composite>
      <val>1</val>
    </GetDataUsingDataContract1>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**It should be noted that we call the WCF service not to send xml messages directly but to call through the proxy class. For information about it, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client).**

Comment: Adding the above is returning the SOAP result instead of the actual dataset